# BizTalk Map HL7 patient identification PID 2.4 to 2.3.1

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper, hl7-v2

I've a requirement where if incoming message have only 1 medicare (MC) info, then output it as it is from 2.4 to 2.3.1, if more than 1 then output the one with no or greater expiration date e.g.

PID|1||520134^^^1021^MR^^20161115~SN601555549^^^1021^SN^^20161115^20161231~33806837263^^^**AUSHIC^MC^^20161115^20201115** (1 MC, output as it is)

> AUSHIC^MC^^20161115^20201115

PID|1||301665024L^^^1021^PENC^^20151204^20161231~504416^^^1021^MR^^20150619~31001600591^^^**AUSHIC^MC^^20150619^20160223~31001600591^^^AUSHIC^MC^^20160222** (multiple MC, output one without expiration date)

> AUSHIC^MC^^20160222

PID|1||301665024L^^^1021^PENC^^20151204^20161231~504416^^^1021^MR^^20150619~31001600591^^^**AUSHIC^MC^^20150619^20160223~31001600591^^^AUSHIC^MC^^20160224^20170223** (multiple MC, output one with greater expiration date)

> AUSHIC^MC^^20160224^20170223

I'm assuming I should be using a XSLT call template for this but I'm not very good with XSLT. Can someone please help me with this?

[attachments](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AhuEOm27RCqSiHZTI9RVPDQetcd_)

Comment: Can you add the XML representation of these messages?  Input and expected output, and also what mapping or XSLT you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Dijkgraaf, I've uploaded the source and destination schema, current map and sample input files

Comment: All relevant information should be in the question, rather than in an external link.  1) Because otherwise if the linked contents disappears the question and answer become useless. 2) People are afraid that external links may be poisonous (e.g. might contain malware).  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve